# Simple RSS reader in php with continuous scrolling

Tags: php, xml, rss

I already made a simple RSS reader, but it only gets me like 25 articles. How do I make it to work like [feedly.com](http://www.feedly.com) or [digg.com](http://www.digg.com), so that it retrieves me many more feeds, and not only 25?

The php code I have:

`$rss = simplexml_load_file('http://www.elespectador.com/rss.xml');`

I already know how to retrieve the title, description, etc. of each item.

Comment: Some feed providers will allow you to make multiple calls, adding a `?page=1` query string to the call. If you read several in a sequence, be careful to put a small delay between them, or you might DoS the server. For providers that do not offer this, you can just read the last 25 articles over time, and this will soon grow to a larger number. You can then paginate them as you wish from your own server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pagination in feeds is arbitrary and you'll have trouble finding a consistent pattern. You should store any data so that now you have 25 elements, but when new ones are added, you keep adding more and more.
Another solution is to use the data from a service like [Superfeedr](http://superfeedr.com/) (I created it!) which stores past content for milions of feeds.